# Why was Pharaoh spared?

Tags: yetziat-mitzrayim, plagues-makkos

Pharaoh & many Egyptians were obviously evil men who enslaved our ancestors & foolishly refused to let them go free. Why was Pharaoh spared? As the main villain in this tragedy you’d think he would pay with his life but his ultimate fate is never addressed.

Comment: "[Exodus 11:5 Why the firstborn](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/68636/1368)"? Duplicate?

Comment: While not an answer to your question I think it’s important to note that death is not the end of a person’s story necessarily, but rather their soul goes on to the next world. From that point of view, the deaths of the first born in Egypt may have hurt their families that remained in our world more than it hurt those that actually died and moved on.

Comment: Individual Egyptians were not killed because they were individually evil, they were killed because God was at war with Egypt.

Comment: https://www1.biu.ac.il/indexE.php?id=20520&pt=1&pid=14401&level=0&cPath=43,14206,14373,14401,20520

Comment: In wars, the victor frequently spares the life of the leader of the vanquished, so he collaborates in the transition to a new ruler.  You need to have someone with authority to negotiate with if you don't want the war to end with everybody on one side killed or enslaved.

Comment: The Midrash says: "They all cried out, as it is stated (Exodus 12:39), "and there was a great outcry in Egypt." They all came to kill Pharaoh. [Ex. R. 18:10]"  Evidently, then, God did not want Pharaoh dead.